# Kendo UI Datagrid - how to pass server pagination param to get new results after click on last item button?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have Kendo datagrid which on onLoad method initialize datagrid and fetch some remote data in JSON from API.

I have for example 20 items to display which are correctly displayed. Problem is that i cannot make request for next values (button next is not active).

How i should to that correctly if i want to pass data to API via POST?

I think, that is it something with serverPaging params.

Thanks for any advice or example, hot to solve this issue.

**Here is exe example of grid init:**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: "multiple cell",
    navigatable: true,
    dataSource: dataPacket,
    filterable: true,
    //page: 2, // unless the serverPaging option is set to true.
    pageSize: 5,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    groupable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 50]
    },
    sortable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columnMenu: true,
    height: 550,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    columns: ["id",
```

**Read function:**

```
  $scope.initGrid = function () {
        var requestParams = {
            "token":"test",
            "data":{
                "test":"test"
            }
        };
        var token = localStorage.getItem($rootScope.lsTokenNameSpace);
        var dataPacket;

        dataPacket = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                // READ FUNCTION
                read: function (options) {
                    console.log("List");
                    // call the service
                    ApiService.doHttpRequest("POST", $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "user/list", requestParams)
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // successful data retrieval
                            console.log("request success");
                            console.log("state: "+status);
                            console.log(data);
                            options.success(data);
                            // do something with data
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // do some stuff
                            console.log("request processing error");
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post Kendo UI API reference for Kendo UI dataSource here. Take a look at it.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging

You need pass needed parameters to fetch more data after first set.

```
myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: { 
                url: "/api/search", 
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                parameterMap: function( data, type ) {
                    return JSON.stringify( { query: $("#searchBox").val(), start: data.page, sort: data.sort, pageSize: data.pageSize } );
                }
            }
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        }
    });
```